# Class called twice after authstatechanges is implemented

Tags: flutter, authentication, dart

After i tried to implement the authStateChanges.listen() for managing user sessions, the class was called twice and it results in 2 Alert Dialogs of the same content, i dont understand what is going on, why is it called twice.

**main() function:**

```
Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  runApp(MaterialApp(home: EntryPoint(), debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false));
}
```

**[EDITED] EntryPoint class:**

```
class EntryPoint extends StatefulWidget {
  _EntryPointState createState() => _EntryPointState();
}

class _EntryPointState extends State<EntryPoint> {
  // Set default `_initialized` and `_error` state to false
  bool _initialized = false;
  bool _error = false;
  FirebaseApp firebaseApp;

  // Define an async function to initialize FlutterFire
  void initializeFlutterFire() async {
    try {
      // Wait for Firebase to initialize and set `_initialized` state to true
      firebaseApp = await Firebase.initializeApp();
      setState(() {
        _initialized = true;
      });
    } catch (e) {
      // Set `_error` state to true if Firebase initialization fails
      setState(() {
        _error = true;
      });
    }
    FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges().listen((User user) {
      if (user == null) {
        Navigator.push(context,
            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) => LoginPage()));
      } else {
        Navigator.push(context,
            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) => MyApp()));
            print('ok');
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    this.initializeFlutterFire();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([DeviceOrientation.portraitUp]);

    return _getLandingPage();
  }
}
```

it logged twice 'ok' in the debug console

```
Restarted application in 1,630ms.
D/ConnectivityManager(27325): unregisterNetworkCallback; CallingUid : 10392, CallingPid : 27325
D/ConnectivityManager(27325): unregisterNetworkCallback; CallingUid : 10392, CallingPid : 27325
W/example.confAp(27325): Accessing hidden method Ldalvik/system/CloseGuard;->close()V (light greylist, linking)
I/flutter (27325): ok
I/flutter (27325): ok
I/flutter (27325): IT IS CONNECTED BOYS
D/ConnectivityManager(27325): requestNetwork; CallingUid : 10392, CallingPid : 27325
W/DynamiteModule(27325): Local module descriptor class for providerinstaller not found.
I/flutter (27325): IT IS CONNECTED BOYS
I/DynamiteModule(27325): Considering local module providerinstaller:0 and remote module providerinstaller:0
W/ProviderInstaller(27325): Failed to load providerinstaller module: No acceptable module found. Local version is 0 and remote version is 0.
D/ConnectivityManager(27325): requestNetwork; CallingUid : 10392, CallingPid : 27325
```

*Edit : added StreamBuilder*

```
Widget _getLandingPage() {
  return StreamBuilder<User>(
    stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges(),
    builder: (BuildContext context, snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.hasData) {
        return MyApp();
      } else {
        return LoginPage();
      }
    },
  );
}
```

Comment: FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges().dislinct().listen blabla

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe, it is the problem that you call `SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([DeviceOrientation.portraitUp]);` inside `build` method. Try to remove it.

The second one, it seems like that problem is related to calling method in `initState`. Try to use `StreamBuilder` to listen `Authentication changes` from Firebase. Apply the same logic for `StreamBuilder`.

Comment: i have added StreamBuilder to listen for auth changes and my codes is as edited in the main question.. but however it shows ```LoginPage()``` for a split second and then shows ```MyApp()```, is there any workaround?

Comment: That is okey, because you have not authenticated. You can delay it using `Future`. Maybe it can help you to increase showing time of `LoginPage`. ```dart import 'dart:async';

void main() async {
  getValue().listen((data) => print(data));
}

Stream<int> getValue() async* {
  await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2));
  yield* authStateChanges();
}

Stream<int> authStateChanges() async* {
  yield 5;
} ``` Here, instead of `listen` you will use `Streambuilder`.